# Excel - Copy the displayed value not the actual value

Tags: vba, excel

I am a pilot, and use a logbook program called Logten Pro. I have the ability to take excel spreadsheets saved from my work flight management software, and import them into Logten Pro using the CSV format.

My problem however, is that the work flight management software, exports the date and time of take-off of a flight into one cell in the following excel format: DD/MM/YYYY  H:MM:SS PM.
This is handled fine by Excel, and is formatted by default to DD/MM/YY even though the actual value is more specific, comprising of the full length date and time group.

This is a problem because Logten Pro will only auto-import the date if it is in DD/MM/YY format, and there is no way to pull out just the displayed DD/MM/YY date rather than the full date time group actual value, unless you manually go through and delete the extra text from the function box.

My question is: Is there a VBA macro that can automatically copy the actual displayed text, and paste it into another cell, changing the actual value as it does, to just the DD/MM/YY value? Additionally, can this be made to work down a whole column rather than individual cells at a time?

Note I have no VBA experience so the perfect answer would just be a complete VBA string I could copy and paste.

Thank You.

Comment: Excel allows copy->paste special, allowing you to retain only the values shown. I don't know macros, but I'd suggest possibly using this to help your search while waiting for answers.

Comment: Please see this post by brettdj. You don't need a macro. Simply use that formula. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834080/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-to-a-date-in-excel/8834174#8834174

Answer (score 12):

As pointed out in the comments, you'd better not use VBA but formulas instead.

This formula:

```
TEXT(A1,"dd-mm-yyy")
```

will return the formated date in a text way. You can drag and drop the formula in the whole range of your cells and `Copy/Paste Special` > `Values` so that you will only have the needed values to get imported in Logten Pro.

Comment: Nice solution as Excel doesn't seems to be a direct way to copy and paste displayed values.

Answer (score 1):

There are three options using formulas.

### Rounddown

Excel stores the date time as a number and uses formatting to display it as a date.
The format is date.time, where the integer is the date and the fraction is the time.

As an example
01/01/2012 10:30:00 PM is stored as 40909.9375

All the values after the decimal place relate to the hours and minutes

So a formula could be used to round the number down to a whole number.

```
=ROUNDDOWN(A1,0)
```

Then format the value as a short date.
It will then display as 01/01/2012

### INT

As above, but using a different formula to get rid of the fraction (time)

```
=INT(A1)
```

### Text

Alternately the date only could be extracted as text using this formula

```
=TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

It will then display as 01/01/2012

Comment: A gentle observation that this answer does largely reflect the earlier contributions from JMax and Siddharth Rrout

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party on this one, but recently came across this as was searching for answers to a similar problem.

Here is the answer I finally came up with.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ValuesToDisplayValues()

    Dim ThisRange As Range, ThisCell As Range

    Set ThisRange = Selection

    For Each ThisCell In ThisRange

        ThisCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Text(ThisCell.Value, ThisCell.NumberFormat)

    Next ThisCell

End Sub
```

This answers the question as asked, apart from the new values are pasted over the existing ones, not into a new cell, as there is no simple way to know where you would want the new values to be pasted. It will work on the whole range of selected cells, so you can do a whole column if needed.