# Convert seconds to normal number

Tags: excel

I have a time as `2012-08-28  12:29:59`
but in a custom format `ss,000` it shows as `59,120`

Now, I want to copy only this to another cell as a normal number.
I have tried `second(xxx)` command, but it returns only `59`. I want the decimal places too.

Help needed.

Thanks

Comment: using VBA you can say `Range("B2") = Range("A1").Text` if A1 is 59,120 and you want what is displayed

Comment: Is there any way to copy just that value 59,120 to another cell without VBA?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel - Copy the displayed value not the actual value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847115/excel-copy-the-displayed-value-not-the-actual-value)

Comment: Thanks @mehow for editing and answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have your datetime in cell A1, try `=--TEXT(A1; "ss,000")`

Answer (score 2):

You can also do that like this

`=MOD(A1*86400;60)`

multiplying by 86400 converts your date/time value to a number of seconds.....then if you take the remainder when divided by 60 you'll get just the decimal seconds