# vba - set data in cell to what date is being displayed

Tags: vba, excel

Probably a simple question, I just cannot pinpoint my figure on it as I still do not fully understand how to approach the different "layers" in excel (what the data actually is in a cell compared to what is being displayed...Ex. date)

I have the following data inside of my cells

```
10/17/2014
10/18/2014
10/19/2014
10/20/2014
```

I ran the following vba code to hopefully reformat that data:

```
Sheet1.Range("C2", "C1000").NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"
```

This makes my data appear as:

```
17-Oct-2014
18-Oct-2014
19-Oct-2014
20-Oct-2014
```

Which is actually what I want to be. Only problem is if I click inside of the actual cell, the data is still in **10/18/2014** format.

Now from my understanding "format" will just change how the data is displayed. I cannot seem to find online how to take what is displaying on the screen and change the value of the cell to what is being displayed. I would think this is a "popular" issue and asked repeatedly so perhaps my search skills are just off and I couldn't locate the article. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

I have read that I could use "Paste Special", but this requires me to format cells and then copy and paste the values manually which is not what I would like. I would like to hopefully completely automate this inside of VBA.

Comment: try this: `Sheet1.Range("C1:C1000").Value = Sheet1.Evaluate("""'"" & INDEX(TEXT(C1:C1000,""dd-mmm-yyyy""),)")`

Comment: @ScottCraner This worked perfectly. I would suggest you go to 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847115/excel-copy-the-displayed-value-not-the-actual-value to provide an answer. That question is from 2012 and viewed 18162 times without an actual answer to the problem (which is very similar to my question, just different use case).

Comment: @ScottCraner and of course if you provide it here I will gladly accept your answer :). Quick question though if I may, why is the ** ' ** needed? I removed it and it broke the code and I cannot figure out why that piece is critical. Thank you.

Comment: As I see it this question and the one you linked are two different questions.  The real answer to the linked one was what Sid Routh linked, It has been deleted, but the question was how to get rid of the time element.  Yours is how to permanently save a date in a certain format.

Comment: The `'` in the beginning forces it to be text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sheet1.Range("C1:C1000").Value = Sheet1.Evaluate("""'"" & INDEX(TEXT(C1:C1000,""dd-mmm-yyyy""),)")
```

The `'` at the beginning forces the output into text.

You could also do it this way:

```
Sheet1.Range("C1:C1000").NumberFormat = "@"
Sheet1.Range("C1:C1000").Value = Sheet1.Evaluate("INDEX(TEXT(C1:C1000,""dd-mmm-yyyy""),)")
```

This will turn numbers that are formatted as dates to text that look like dates.  In other words if any reference to or mathematical formulas on these cells will need to covert them back to numbers.

Comment: Pefect! Second question if I may. I am trying to loop through every cell to set a value and I modified your code to be `Cells(Q, timeStart).Value = Evaluate("""'"" & INDEX(TEXT(timeStart:Q ,""dd/mmm/yyyy""),)")`  **Q** is a for loop that loops until the last row in that column (Q = row number). **timeStart** = Column number. I appear to be referencing it incorrectly. Any chance you could shed some quick comment light?

Comment: The INDEX() will do the whole range at once: `Sheet1.Range(sheet1.Cells(2,timestart),Sheet1.Cells(lastrow,timestart)).value = Sheet1.Evaluate("""'"" & INDEX(TEXT(" & Sheet1.Range(sheet1.Cells(2,timestart),Sheet1.Cells(lastrow,timestart)).Address(0,0) & ",""dd-mmm-yyyy""),)")`  No loop needed.

Comment: VBA Master! Thank you so much for your help.