# vba - Range loop provided Jan1900 date error

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working with members of the stack exchange community over the past 4 days while I work extensively in VBA (so ive been using vba for 4 days :) ). I had an issue that required me to take the date that was being presented and standardize the format (dates were different throughout sheet). [vba - set data in cell to what date is being displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36344315/vba-set-data-in-cell-to-what-date-is-being-displayed/36344763?noredirect=1#comment60311663_36344763)

This worked for what I was trying to accomplish. There was a side-effect where if a cell contained no data, it would default to 01/Jan/1900.

Code is below.

```
timestart = 1      #Column 1
completeBad = 2    #Column 2
timeSet = 24       #Column 24
completeTime = 25  #Column 25
lastrow = 1000

Range(Cells(2, timeSet), Cells(lastrow, completeTime)).NumberFormat = "@"
Range(Cells(2, timeSet), Cells(lastrow, timeSet)).NumberFormat = "@"
Range(Cells(2, timestart), Cells(lastrow, timestart)).Value = Evaluate("""'"" & INDEX(TEXT(" & Range(Cells(2, timestart), Cells(lastrow, timestart)).Address(0, 0) & ",""dd/mmm/yyyy""),)")
Range(Cells(2, completeBad), Cells(lastrow, completeBad)).Value = Evaluate("""'"" & INDEX(TEXT(" & Range(Cells(2, completeBad), Cells(2, completeBad)).Address(0, 0) & ",""dd/mmm/yyyy""),)")
For Q = 2 To lastrow
  Cells(Q, timeSet).Value = Cells(Q, timestart).Value
  Cells(Q, completeTime).Value = Cells(Q, completeBad).Value
next Q
```

Nothing  crazy going on here. Justs sets the format/text of a cell, and copies the data to a cell that is set up for text.

This gives me a lot of cells with `01/Jan/1900` being displayed if the `timestart` and `completeBad` cells have no data in them.

I am trying to get this to loop through each cell. My code is below:

```
timestart = 1      #Column 1
completeBad = 2    #Column 2
timeSet = 24       #Column 24
completeTime = 25  #Column 25
lastrow = 1000
For Q = 2 To lastrow
If Cells(Q, timestart) <> "" Then
  Range(Cells(Q, timestart), Cells(Q, timestart)).Value = Evaluate("""'"" & INDEX(TEXT(" & Range(Cells(Q, timestart), Cells(Q, timestart)).Address(0, 0) & ",""dd/mmm/yyyy""),)")
  Cells(Q, timeSet).Value = Cells(Q, timestart).Value
End If
If Cells(Q, projCom) <> "" Then
  Range(Cells(Q, completeBad), Cells(Q, completeBad)).Value = Evaluate("""'"" & INDEX(TEXT(" & Range(Cells(Q, completeBad), Cells(Q, completeBad)).Address(0, 0) & ",""dd/mmm/yyyy""),)")
  Cells(Q, completeTime).Value = Cells(Q, completeBad).Value
End If
```

I tried to use `range` to select a single cell as at least with `range` the code was modifying my data for me.

This returns `#VALUE!` in all of my cells (for my date column I call). I have tried multiple ways to only modify one cell at a time and I keep receiving `#VALUE!` or it errors out on my code and I cannot figure out why. Another example that does not work for my loop is below.  Can someone shed some light on what I am doing wrong with calling either the full code above or my code below (code below replaced the `range` used in my for loop, I just didn't want to retype everything).

```
Cells(Q, timestart).Value = Evaluate("""'"" & INDEX(TEXT(" & Cells(Q, timestart).Address(0, 0) & ",""dd/mmm/yyyy""),)")
```

Comment: **#Column 1/2/24/25** is not actually part of my code. I included this for readability for everyone. If there is a typo it is probably just my horrible ninja typing skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this will ignore the blanks:

```
timestart = 1      '#Column 1
completeBad = 2    '#Column 2
timeSet = 24       '#Column 24
completeTime = 25  '#Column 25
lastrow = 1000
With Sheets(looping)
    With .Range(.Cells(2, timestart), .Cells(lastrow, timestart))
        .Value = Evaluate("""'"" & INDEX(IF(" & .Address(0, 0) & "<>"""",TEXT(" & .Address(0, 0) & ",""dd/mmm/yyyy""),""""),)")
    End With
    With .Range(.Cells(2, completeBad), .Cells(lastrow, completeBad))
        .Value = Evaluate("""'"" & INDEX(IF(" & .Address(0, 0) & "<>"""",TEXT(" & .Address(0, 0) & ",""dd/mmm/yyyy""),""""),)")
    End With
End With
```

Comment: You sir, are amazing! Thank you very much. Again :)

Comment: nice but just a precaution... See [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962890/2-ways-for-clearcontents-on-vba-excel-but-1-work-fine-why)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I agree the OP should assign the parentage to the range objects.  Without seeing the rest of the code it was difficult to make any assumptions.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I have my entire module inside of a for loop that sets the `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(looping).Activate`

Comment: @SiddharthRout not 100% sure if that resolves the issue you are talking about but that is how I am calling what worksheet I am on.

Comment: @bluerojo. You may want to see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179) :)

Comment: @bluerojo then you should simply use another With Block I will edit my answer to show.

Comment: @ScottCraner Just to let you know. This piece of code is only a small chunk of the 500+ lines for this one module (5 in all right now). It resolves some heavy parsing of data and formatting issues, as well as calculates new fields based off of status fields etc.

Comment: @SiddharthRout that is very interesting. I will have to try to implement this code into my modules.

Comment: @bluerojo I added only for information.  I hope you have split up your code so that any duplicated routines are in their own.  Also, I agree with Siddarth, Avoid the `.Select` or `.Activate`. It slows down the code and is not needed in most cases.

Comment: @ScottCraner Honestly my entire code could/should definitely be refactored (if time permits). As I started out with no knowledge of the full extent of the problem and really no VBA experience (Unix/Linux man though), my code is probably horrendous for anyone to look at with a moderate level of VBA experience.